# how to manipulate char array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, char, buffer

I have something like this.

```
char header[4096]; //header information from a file
```

there is a field called `startByteOffset` which is `8 bytes` (offset in header is 8 too) and then there is `endByteOffset` which is `8 bytes` in lenght too.(offset in header is 16).
I need to change the `endByteOffset`. How to do that? Thanks. 
Let me know if it is not clear enough.

Comment: Its not clear enough

Comment: header[someOffset] = someValue; header[someOtherOffset] = someOtherValue;

Comment: If there are fields in this header then why declare it as a char array?  It is a struct so define it as such.  You can then create a union if you also need to access it as a char array.

Comment: @user1489813: I suggest you declare your header as `unsigned char` or preferably `uint8_t`.  Unsigned let's you use all 8 bits.  The `char` type may be signed or unsigned, depending on the compiler.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasMatthews . I will try to use struct of fields rather than storing in char array as Carey suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To break an integer into characters (bytes) you can use shifting and masking.

```
uint64_t value = /* ... */;
header[endbyteoffset]   = value         & 0xff;
header[endbyteoffset+1] = (value >> 8)  & 0xff;
header[endbyteoffset+2] = (value >> 16) & 0xff;
header[endbyteoffset+3] = (value >> 24) & 0xff;
// ...
header[endbyteoffset+7] = (value >> 56) & 0xff;
```

You'll need to know if the values are to be stored in *little-endian* or *big-endian* order. The example I provided above is for little-endian; for big-endian you just reverse the order of the shifts, starting with the largest shift first.